# Estimating coin bias from multiple adversary observations

Tags: jags, pymc, stan

I have a set of biased coins $N$, where each coin has a different bias $\theta_i$ (probability of heads for $i$th coin is $\theta_i$). This bias is unknown and needs to be estimated.

There are $K$ experts who independently from each other toss each coin exactly once, observe the value and report it. Alas, the experts are not faithful, with probability $p_j$, the $j$th expert will report the heads for tails, or tails for heads. The flipping probability is known to be less than 0.5 for all experts and needs to be estimated.

What would be the appropriate model for such problem? I am new to probabilistic programming and any advice on reading, experimenting would be great.

I am familiar with PyMC3, some JAGS and very little Stan.

Comment: Is the probability to lie different for each expert?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Yes, the probability to lie is different for each expert.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a model that estimates coin bias and flipping probabilities of three adversaries.

```
#
# Estimate coin bias given multiple observations from adversarial experts.
#

import sys

import pymc3 as pm
import numpy as np
import theano.tensor as tt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.optimize import fmin_powell
from scipy.stats.distributions import bernoulli

p_true = 0.1                                # true coin bias (probability of heads)
a_true = np.array( [ 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 ] )      # noise (flipping probability)

N = 1000        # number of coin observations
K = 3           # number of experts

# generate reference data
X = bernoulli.rvs( size=N, p=p_true )

# corrupt data with noise
Y = np.zeros( (K,N) )
for k in range( K ):
    Y[k,:] = X
    flip_or_not = bernoulli.rvs( size=N, p=a_true[k] )
    for i in range( N ):
        if flip_or_not[i] == 1:
            if Y[k,i] == 1:
                Y[k,i] = 0
            else:
                Y[k,i] = 1

model = pm.Model()

with model:
    alpha0 = pm.HalfCauchy( 'alpha0', beta=1 )
    beta0 = pm.HalfCauchy( 'beta0', beta=1 )

    p = pm.Beta( 'p', alpha=alpha0, beta=beta0 )
    a = pm.Uniform( 'a', lower=0, upper=0.5, shape=K )

    q = a + p - 2 * a * p

    y_hidden = pm.Bernoulli('y_hidden_' + str(k), p=p, shape=N)

    for k in range( K ):
        y_obs = pm.Bernoulli( 'y_obs_' + str(k), p=q[k], observed=Y[k,:] )
        pot = pm.Potential( 'pot_' + str(k), -1000000 * ( tt.sum( (y_hidden - y_obs)**2 ) ) )

    #for i in range( N ):
    #    potential = pm.Potential( 'potential_' + str(i), -1000*(y_hidden[i] - y_obs[i]) ** 2 )

    start = pm.find_MAP()
    step = pm.NUTS( scaling=start )
    trace = pm.sample( 1000, start=start, step=step )

varnames = [ 'a', 'p' ]

pm.traceplot( trace, varnames=varnames )
#pm.autocorrplot( trace )
plt.show()
```